# Django TemplateSyntaxErrors in generic date based Class views

Tags: django

I'm trying to update an old Django project (last working at Django 1.4) to use class based generic views (In Django 1.5)

The following used to work

Template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for month in date_list %}
        <h2><a href="{% url coltrane_entry_archive_month year,month|date:"b" %}">{{ month|date:"F" }}</a></h2>
        <h2>Blah</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
...   
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', dict(entry_info_dict,make_object_list=True), 'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
...
)
```

however when I updated the urls.py to use generic class

```
class ArticleYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    date_field = "pub_date"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True

urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url(
        r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
        ArticleYearArchiveView.as_view(),
        name='coltrane_entry_archive_year'
    ),
    url(
        r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$',
        dates.MonthArchiveView.as_view(
            template_name='coltrane/entry_archive_month.html',
            queryset=Entry.objects.filter(status=Entry.LIVE_STATUS),
            date_field='pub_date'),
        name="coltrane_entry_archive_month"
    ),
...
)
```

the following TemplateSyntaxError starts appearing:

**Could not parse some characters: year|,month||date:"b"**

I can render the template and check what's being passed to coltrane_entry_archive_month using the following:

```
{% for month in date_list %}
    {{ year }}
    {{ month|date:"b" }}
{% endfor %}
```

I did notice that {{ year }} is being rendered as 'Jan. 1, 2013' rather than '2013' that matches the regex in the url. This I don't understand.

Futher I then tried to render the following:

```
{% for month in date_list %}
    {% url "coltrane_entry_archive_month" "2013","apr" %}
{% endfor %}
```

No joy, this time the TemplateSyntaxError is:

**Could not parse the remainder: ',"apr"' from '"2013","apr"'**

Both generic class views and the url seem to be largish topics in Django so any pointers would be very welcome indeed!

Comment: `"{% url coltrane_entry_archive_month year,month|date:"b" %}"` should be `'{% url coltrane_entry_archive_month year month|date:"b" %}'`

Comment: karthikr - thanks. I've accepted the answer below but appreciate your comments and solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag doesn't take comma-separated arguments, just list them with a space.

```
{% for month in date_list %}
    {% url "coltrane_entry_archive_month" "2013" "apr" %}
{% endfor %}
```

which means you need to change your actual template to

```
{% url "coltrane_entry_archive_month" year month|date:"b" %}
```

Also just a note (which I noticed you followed in your second example)

> Don’t forget to put quotes around the function path or pattern name!
>
> Changed in Django 1.5: The first parameter used not to be quoted,
>   which was inconsistent with other template tags. Since Django 1.5, it
>   is evaluated according to the usual rules: it can be a quoted string
>   or a variable that will be looked up in the context.

Comment: Heh wouldn't be the first time I've been stumped over a comma... Thanks for your answer which does work. A moot point but I had to change {{ year }} to {{ month|date:"Y" }} to suit the url pattern - otherwise I get a NoReverseMatch error. I'm not sure why it doesn't render like it used to.

Comment: Just noticed the link you posted to the url built in template tags - that's great I hadn't managed to find it in the help.

Comment: It looks like it is being passed as a date if it is outputting as `Jan. 1, 2013` so using the date filter on it should be fine. As for why it does that, I don't know either...

Comment: Yes I was using the {{year}} variable outside of the template loop as well and have just tried the date filter on it which works just fine.